# VS Code Dart Formatter Dot New Line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am coding on vs code with Flutter & Dart. Although I have not made any changes, the dart format editor works as follows. I just want it to move to a new line after the commas. My code becomes very complicated in this state.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik4rz.png)

I did a search because I did not know anything about the subject, but I did not get any results.

Answer (score 0):

On your vscode top bar under "View" select "wordwrap" or
in your vscode settings search for wordwrap.